# How to get D3D11 INFO: directx debug layer data on surface pro?

Tags: winrt-xaml, directx-11

I am debugging resource loss and can get create/destroy "D3D11 INFO:" messages when running on the desktop and simulator. But when I run on the Surface Pro I get "D3D11 ERROR:" messages but not any infos.

I found an old post about hacking the debug flag in on a breakpoint but the flag seems to be set correctly. Also did my best to set the exe in the dxdiag app but not sure if/how that matters remotely.

Has anyone seen these messages coming out or know what you need to do to get them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the source, the best thing to do would be to use the debug interface directly [ID3D11Debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476366(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ID3D11InfoQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476538(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
 #ifdef _DEBUG
 deviceCreationFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
 #endif

 // deviceCreationFlags is passed to D3D11CreateDevice as 'Flags' which is the fourth parameter

 ID3D11Debug *d3dDebug = nullptr;
 if( SUCCEEDED( d3dDevice->QueryInterface( __uuidof(ID3D11Debug), (void**)&d3dDebug ) ) )
 {
    ID3D11InfoQueue *d3dInfoQueue = nullptr;
    if( SUCCEEDED( d3dDebug->QueryInterface( __uuidof(ID3D11InfoQueue), (void**)&d3dInfoQueue ) ) )
    {
 #ifdef _DEBUG
    d3dInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity( D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_CORRUPTION, true );
    d3dInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity( D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR, true );
 #endif
```

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) blog post.

Comment: Hi Chuck: I've read your blog and used the code before. Good stuff.  But it doesn't seem to do what I want here. The messages I get in the sim are like "D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Sampler: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x1E19DDEC, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097267: CREATE_SAMPLER]" and I parse the log matching creates, destroys and addresses. With the code you have above I now get some "D3D11 ** BREAK **" messages but I still get no D3D11 INFO:'s on the Surface Pro. This is my first time debugging on the device.

Comment: The Surface Pro is an x86/x64 platform, so it should be running the exact same SDK Debug Layer that is found on the "desktop". Just to clarify, you do not mean Surface RT which is the ARM-platform, correct? You could try a quick test using AddApplicationMessage with D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_INFO to see if it shows up.

Comment: Wow! My mistake. It is an RT. Thanks for setting me straight Chuck. But still does that means the debug layer in RT isn't providing those messages? They were very valuable. If you reply as an answer, or update your current one I'll mark it answered. Thanks again.